# Is every finite non-abelian simple group generated by involutions?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $ G $ be a finite non-abelian simple group. Is it true that the set of involutions
$$
\{ g: g\in G, g^2=1 \}
$$
generates $ G $?

For example consider the group $ G=A_5 $ of order $ 60 $. The involutions are the $ 15 $ permutations of cycle type $ (23)(45) $. These indeed generate all of $ A_5 $ since they can immediately be seen to generate all $ 20 $ of the 3 cycles e.g. $ (123)=(12)(45)(23)(45) $. And $ 20+15=35 $ is greater than any proper divisor of $ 60 $.

Comment: Hint: Use simplicity of $G$ and Feit–Thompson theorem.

Comment: The answer is no, but I suspect you meant finite simple groups. In that case they are all generated by three involutions.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes let me put in finite. I guess $ PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ is an example of an infinite non-abelian simple group not generated by involutions.

Comment: Yes, if you take the subgroup generated by the elements of order $2,$ then that subgroup is a normal subgroup, since if $g^2=1,$ then $(hgh^{-1})^2=1.$

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh I see the conjugate of an involution is another involution so the set of all involutions is fixed under conjugation and thus the group it generates is normal.  So by simplicity $ G $ is either generated by involutions or has no involutions. In some infinite cases like $ PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ there are no involutions. But if $ |G| $ is finite then we can apply Feit-Thompson and order $ |G| $ must be even so by Cayley's theorem there is an involution so involutions generate all of $ G $.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can we make a similar argument for almost simple groups, or are there certain groups like $ Aut(A_6) $ with odd order automorphisms which are not generated by involutions? I suppose maybe all the involutions in $ Aut(A_6) $ are contained in the $ S_6 $ subgroup?

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb C})$ contins involutions, so it is generated by involutions. But there are torsion-free infinite simple groups, which are clearly no generated by involutions. You seem to have answered your question about almost simple groups yourself. $A_6.3$ cannot be generated by involutions.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ya I was just checking. What is an example of a torsion free infinite simple group?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: For instance, Burger-Mozes groups are finitely presented infinite simple and torsion-free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjugate of an involution is another involution.

So the set of all involutions is fixed under conjugation and thus the group it generates is normal.

So by simplicity $ G $ is either generated by involutions or has no involutions.

Since $ |G| $ is finite non-abelian and simple then it is finite and nonsolvable thus we can apply Feit-Thompson to conclude that $ |G| $ is even. Thus by Cayley's theorem $ G $ contains an element of order $ 2 $.

So the subgroup generated by involutions is not trivial and by the reasoning above $ G $ is generated by involutions.

Comment: Related and interesting about minimal number of involutions generating (usually 3 and two of them commute) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26297/which-finite-groups-are-generated-by-n-involutions