# Finite perfect group generated by odd powers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a finite perfect group. Is it true that the the set
$$
\{ g^n: g \in G \}
$$
generates $ G $ for any odd $ n $?

This is equivalent to asking if the set
$$
\{ g^n: g \in G \}
$$
generates $ G $ for $ n $ the largest odd divisor of $ |G| $.

And it is equivalent to $ G $ being generated by all its elements of order a power of $ 2 $.

If $ G $ is a finite perfect group which is moreover simple, then the answer is yes since $ G $ is generated by involutions see [Is every finite non-abelian simple group generated by involutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670131/is-every-finite-non-abelian-simple-group-generated-by-involutions?noredirect=1#comment9870351_4670131)

Since the subgroup generated by all elements of order a power of $ 2 $ is a normal subgroup then to show the claim it is enough to show that no finite perfect group has a normal subgroup containing all its elements of order a power of $ 2 $.

Comment: Do you know that every non-trivial finite perfect group is even? Because the subgroup generated by the elements of order a power of $2$ must be a normal subgroup, $H,$ and thus $G/H$ is the quotient of a perfect group. But $G/H$ has no elements of order $2.$

Comment: If there are non-trivial odd perfect groups, then they would be a counterexample, since we could choose $n=|G|.$

Comment: The reason $H$ is normal is that if $h$ has order $2^k,$ then each conjugate $ghg^{-1}$ has the same order.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews there are no non-trivial perfect groups of odd order by Feit-Thompson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem

Comment: Then you are done - the quotient group $G/H$ is perfect and odd, so it has to be trivial.

Comment: Basically, $H$ contains a Sylow $2$-subgroup, so $|G|/|H|$ must be odd. But my group theory is somewhat rusty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the elements of order $2^k.$

1. $H$ is a normal subgroup. This is because the conjugate of an element of order $2^k$ is also of order $2^k.$
2. $G/H$ is perfect, because the quotient of a perfect group is perfect.
3. $H$ contains a Sylow $2$-subgroups
4. So $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$ must be odd.

But there are no odd non-trivial perfect groups.

Comment: Nice answer! I guess this shows in general that if the only odd order quotient of $ G $ is trivial then $ G $ must be generated by elements of order $ 2^k $.